# Unable to wget/curl from a kubernetes Pod with https/443

Tags: docker, curl, networking, kubernetes

I am not able to curl/wget any URL with https. They're all giving connection refused errors. Here's what I've observed so far:

1. When I curl any URL with https from any pod, the domain gets resolved to the different IP address than the intended one. I verified this with `dig domainname` and `curl`ing the same domainname. Both IP's were different
2. For debugging purpose, I tried the same scenario from a kubelet docker container and it worked. But if I tried the same from another app container, it fails.

Any idea what might be wrong? I am sure, there is some issue with networking. Any more steps for debugging?

The cluster is setup with RKE on bare-metal which uses canal for networking.

The website I am trying to curl is updates.jenkins.io and here's the nslookup output

```
bash-4.4# nslookup updates.jenkins.io
Server:     10.43.0.10
Address:    10.43.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
updates.jenkins.io.domain.name  canonical name = io.domain.name.
Name:   io.domain.name
Address: 185.82.212.199
```

And nslookup from the node gives

```
root@n4:/home# nslookup updates.jenkins.io
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
updates.jenkins.io  canonical name = mirrors.jenkins.io.
Name:   mirrors.jenkins.io
Address: 52.202.51.185
```

As far as I can see, it is trying to connect to io.domain.name and not updates.jenkins.io.

Further inspection, all domains ending with .io are causing the issue. Here'a another one:

```
bash-4.4# nslookup test.io
Server:     10.43.0.10
Address:    10.43.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
test.io.domain.name canonical name = io.domain.name.
Name:   io.domain.name
Address: 185.82.212.199
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to another pod or to something on the internet?

Comment: Do you have a proxy active?

Comment: No, not that I know of. The strange thing is I am able to curl/wget any https URL from the node but not from the pods.

Comment: @coderanger I am trying to setup jenkins with helm. The init container of jenkins tries to install some plugins from updates.jenkins.io with curl and it fails. Now, for debugging purpose, I tried to curl other https URL from a busybox and it failed too.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande Have you checked out https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there was some issue with `/etc/resolv.conf`. It was missing the correct nameserver entry. Once that was resolved, and the system components were restarted, everything was working.